# How PHP extensions are loaded?

Tags: php

I have typed `php -m` it shows a bunch of module names. but Inside of my `php.ini` file all extensions are commented . how does that work?

Comment: Use phpinfo() to check exact loaded php.ini

Answer (score 0):

There is a different `php.ini` for `CLI`

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few core modules that are "built in" and loaded automatically. You can't turn them off or stop them from being loaded. Modules referenced in the INI file are "extra" and it is up to the end user to enable (load) them or not.

The modules loaded automatically (built in) are:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqlnd
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
```